# loading properties file in spring testing with junit

Tags: java, spring, integration-testing

I'm trying to create some JUnit tests for our Spring application. In order to load the context I need to access 2 properties files in the following directory tree:

```
-settings
  -default (properties common to every developer and enviroment)
    -common.properties
  -dev (properties regarding my local environment, ignored in commits)
    -environment.properties
-src (settings is in the same level as src folder)
  -...
```

We also have folders for production, qa... in the same level as dev and default.

I'm trying to load both files using @PropertiesSources but I for what I've read I should do something like:

```
@PropertiesSource("classpath:../settings/default/common.properties")
```

But that is not working. Anyone has had this problem before?

Bonus question:

My personal folder "dev" is not the same for everyone here. Some people call it "local" or "localhost"... We can just agree to the same name, but when we package the app, we pass a maven argument like -Dsettings=dev and we have a plugin that only includes that file in the war.

If I can do something like that in tests it would be great, but if not, we'll just settle on the same name for everyone.

Thanks in advance,

Gonzalo

Answer (score 0):

I found the right configuration:

```
@PropertiesSource("file:settings/default/common.properties")
```

Answer (score -2):

Hi Gonzalo why are you using two dots
try it
classpath:settings/default/common.properties

Comment: I red somewhere that classpath:MY_PATH starts in src. I've also tried other combinations. By the way, to ask for more info about the problem you should use the comments of the question instead of posting and answer. :D

Comment: If the resource is located in a particular package, you can specify the absolute path from the classpath root.
"classpath:settings/default/common.properties" should be correct
and you can also check detail about @TestPropertySource annotation